# HTML form to multiple emails

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a form with 9 text fields where users can input their friends' emails. The recipients will receive HTML email in their inbox.

Question, how do I make it so that the users don't have to input in all the 9 text fields? As for now, when I just enter an email on 1 field, they will display 8 errors (for each unfilled text field)

**Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 503 Bad sequence of commands. You must specify the recipients of a message before you can send it in C:\httpdocs\PRM\mail-ori.php on line 62**

Comment: can you please show some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Form fields.

```
    <input type="text" name="email[]" />
    <input type="text" name="email[]" />
    <input type="text" name="email[]" />
    <input type="text" name="email[]" />
    <input type="text" name="email[]" />
    <input type="text" name="email[]" />
    <input type="text" name="email[]" />
    <input type="text" name="email[]" />
    <input type="text" name="email[]" />
```

If you remove the nulls your program will not throw any errors. Write this bellow condition in action form.

```
    <?php
    $AllEmails=$_REQUEST['email'];

    // To remove nulls.
    $emails=array_filter($AllEmails);

    for($itr=0; $itr<count($emails); $itr++)
    {
        echo "Sent the mail to mail_ID: ".$emails[$itr];
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Ah very nice, thanks! How do I add in $to, $subject, $message, $headers in the code?

Comment: Keep your mailing script in for loop and assign $emails[$itr] to $to. $to=$emails[$itr];